# Getting could not authenticate 32 while posting reply via Twitter API

Tags: java, twitter

im working on a Twitter Library , so far i have been able to successfully post tweets using API , so if i try to reply to a particular tweet using this parameter

```
in_reply_to_status_id=someid
```

im getting

```
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

url looks like this

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=%40solohello%20replying&in_reply_to_status_id=110708411295356799XXX
```

if i tried to post with out in_reply_to_status_id parameter it works fine

Answer (score 1):

this issue occurred because i did not include the parameter

```
in_reply_to_status_id=11071303*******
```

in signature generation , once i added it it got posted, seems like we have to add all the URL parameters for signature generation